# Python3 del object from list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to del an object in my list inside my loop but it's not working.

```
data = []

data.append({
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2
})

data.append({
    'one': 3,
    'two': 4
})

data.append({
    'one': 5,
    'two': 6
})

for d in data:
    if d['one'] == 3:
        del d
```

It's impossible to delete my object like that ? `del d`

The only one solution that I found is to create a counter then delete with index in the data list `del data[x]`

Comment: No. You can't delete it without index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del d` unbinds the name `d`, which is *just another reference* to one of the dictionaries in `data`. Since references are reassigned and unbound independently (see this [classic](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)) you won't see any changes to `data`.

In general, it is [error prone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) to remove items from a list while iterating over it.

The conventional wisdom aquired from hundreds of years of programming Python says to build a new list and rebind the name.

```
>>> data = [d for d in data if d['one'] != 3]
>>> data
[{'two': 2, 'one': 1}, {'two': 6, 'one': 5}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
data = filter(lambda x: x['one'] != 3, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete items from a list while you are iterating through it because the list indices change as you delete elements. Also `del d` simply deleted the name `d`, the dictionary will still exist in the list.

The best solution here is to create a new list with the unwanted elements filtered out:

```
data = [d for d in data if d['one'] != 3]
```

If it is important to modify the existing list `data` because there are other references to it that must also see the changes you can use a slice assignment to update the original list, but this is not usually needed:

```
data[:] = [d for d in data if d['one'] != 3]
```